# Getting the Raspberry Camera V3 (IMX708) to work on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, camera

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3 (IMX708) for my new ROS2 robot project.
I managed to get the camera working with the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS quite easily. However, I have been struggling to get it to work with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. (I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB, by the way)

I tried compiling `libcamera` and `libcamera-apps` according to Raspberry Pi's documentation (https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#building-libcamera-and-libcamera-apps) and was able to install them successfully that way.

However, when I tried to use the `libcamera-hello` command, it errored out saying that no cameras were available.

I also tried an old Raspberry Pi Camera V1.3 (OV5647) but got the same error.

Any help or advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have same problem. But with RPI 3. After install libcamera-tools.
libcamera: command not found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should compile imx708.dtbo for firmware overlays and compile imx708.ko for kernel module to let raspberry pi camera module v3 work on ubuntu 22.04 or 20.04 .

I'v tried it on ubuntu 20.04 but the kernel is too old to compile the kernel module imx708.ko.